# Customize Android Pull-To-Refresh Icon

Tags: android, user-interface, pull-to-refresh

is it possible to replace the Icon of the Pull-To-Reload, the circle-arrow, with something else?

[image: Pull-To-Reload Icon]

I'd like to have something like a trash-can instead.

Thanks,
Georg

Comment: which P-T-R library do you use?

Comment: The default `SwipeRefreshLayout ` but the one gatnowurry suggested works fine, thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the SwipeRefreshLayout, it seems there is no way to change the icon or animation for it yet. You can change the colors for the animation of spinning lines with the `setColorSchemeColors` method.

Some external pull to refresh libraries do let you do it, like [Ultra Pull to Refresh](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-Ultra-Pull-To-Refresh) by liaohuqiu. It seems to allow a lot of customisation of the effect.

Comment: That Ultra Pull thing looks awesome... THANKS!